# Parsing JSON response in JSP

Tags: json, jsp

```
{"name":"Arnav","surname":"Rodrigues","gender":"male","region":"India"}
```

How do I parse this JSON response in JSP/Java.

For Ex:

```
Name: Arnav
Surname: Rodrigues
```

Comment: how you are reading the response? is it ajax request? Could you share code where do you want to read this response?

Answer (score 0):

```
String jsonStr = '{"name":"Arnav","surname":"Rodrigues","gender":"male","region":"India"}';
JSONObject myObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(jsonStr);  
// myObject.name, myObject.surname, ...
```

Comment: This response I am getting through a URL. SO can I pass the value of URL in that string?

Comment: The response you get from that URL after an HTTP request? Yes

Comment: yupp..I am getting this response from http://uinames.com/api/?region=india

Comment: I am getting this error: - Invalid character constant at  '{"name"

Comment: How do you pass the variable into JSONValue.parse()?

Comment: I am not sure about it. What i need to do is to get the response from that URL and show it in the JSP page.